# how is the path in a server configuration in eclipse created?

Tags: java, eclipse

I installed a new jdk, and updated Installed JREs in Windows, Properties, Java in eclipse.

I have a Server configuration (in which I start a application server), and there  I updated Java home. (Apparently this is also needed, althought threre is a default in Installed JREs).

But when I start this Server configuration, I see a path with the old jdk's bin/ and the new jdk's bin/. Probably because the old jdk is in front, this old jdk's bin/ is taken.

How is this path created, so how can I remove the old jdk?

Comment: consult this: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click your project > properties
2. Select “Java Build Path” on left, then “JRE System Library”, click
   Edit…
3. Select "Workspace Default JRE"
4. Click "Installed JREs"
5. If you see JRE you want in the list select it (selecting a JDK is OK
   too) If not, click Search…, navigate to Computer > Windows C: >
   Program Files > Java, then 
   click OK
6. Now you should see all installed JREs, select the one you want Click
   OK/Finish a million times

> Note: > Change **JAVA_HOME** environment variable to the JDK's folder
>   too